# In a formula, access a column (by its number) in Excel

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula

Given that `A1` cell contains a number, say `5` (calculated from other input), how do I use this to access the fourth column, i. e. `E:E`?

[image: example worksheet]

In the example, how to use the value of `A1` to refer to the "baz1" , ... column E?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this is if you put this formula next to your table

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,A1),2),ROW(),":",LEFT(ADDRESS(1,A1),2),ROW())`

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below formula in cell `A5` and drag down,

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROW(1:1),$A$1-1)
```

[image]

Changing cell value `A1`, would automatically reflect in the cells `A5 to A7`,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using `$1:$1048576` to reference the whole worksheet,

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576, 2, $A$1)
=INDEX($1:$1048576, 3, $A$1)
=INDEX($1:$1048576, 4, $A$1)
```

copy the values of `E2`, `E3`, and `E4`.

Comment: @teylyn this kind of blogging is [encouraged on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). (But that's not what happened, I did in fact find an answer after asking.) If you think this has already been answered on here, I appreciate a pointer. Glad to help, even though I ... don't quite understand the point of _your_ question :-D